# Include state data in B2C sign in

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Users open a page with query string parameters, after which they need to sign in to Azure B2C. After sign in is complete I would like the query string values back but cannot figure how to do it. At the moment the best option seems to be to include it as state data but I'm not sure how. Or should I add it to the `AuthenticationProperties` Any thoughts? Below is my Sign in navigation as in the sample app

```cs
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
    new AuthenticationProperties
    (
        new Dictionary<string, string> { { Startup.PolicyKey, Startup.SignInPolicyId } }
    )
    { RedirectUri = "/", },
    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```